# Problema al integrar Firebase con Nativescript

Tags: firebase

Buenas tardes.

Estoy empezando un proyecto con Nativescript y acabo de empezar a tocarlo. Quiero integrarlo con Firebase cy me sale un error. Se construye la aplicación correctamente pero cuando voy a inicializarla me sale una pantalla de error y no me deja hacer nada. Lo último que he hecho es instalar el plugin y importarlo en mi app.module.ts de la siguiente manera:
 import firebase = require ('nativescript-plugin-firebase');

Como ya he dicho esto me funciona bien, pero al inicializarse la app desde mi telefono me sale una pantalla con un error que dice: Error: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.

Entre otras cosas, pero este es el error que me dice. He adjuntado una foto para que se vea mejor. Lo que no entiendo es lo que me dice de Facebook, ya que no he añadido nada de facebook, simplemente el plugin de Firebase. No se si se me esta escapando algo, por que justo estoy empezando a tocar Nativescipt.. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a solucionarlo ya que acabo de empezar y ya estoy atascado..

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

- Verifica que agregaste correctamente tu app a la consola de firebase(el id mas que todo) y que tienes activa la autenticacion de facebook desde la consola.

Para mi se soluciono con hacer tns platform remove android/ios y volver a correr

Answer (score 0):

Luego de revisar noté que puede ser por esta razón. Verifica que tengas los dos pasos de la documentación:

1. Agregar al AndroidManifest (app/App_Resources/Android) dentro de la etiqueta Application

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
   ```
2. Crea un archivo "facebooklogin.xml" dentro de "app/App_Resources/Android/values" que contenga:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <resources>
   <string name="facebook_app_id">tufacebookid</string>
   </resources>
   ```

Comment: @GDP tu [sugerencia de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/64464) es buena, pero ve con cuidado al modificar código de la gente. Si quieres que el bloque de código aparezca en un listado, pon 8 espacios delante (4 como siempre + 4 por estar en lista). Mira cómo lo edité :)

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui . Es que en su código original no aparecia el meta. Y no le he visto otra manera que ponerle un espacio entre etiquetas. Anotado para la proxima. No sabia que lista habia que darle mas.